# How to access/change JSON value with python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm working on making a rudimentary physics calculator. I have a json file that contains *this*.
I'm trying to use Python to transfer the json object to a Python dictionary, change the value for the "value" key into user input. Here's what I have so far.

```
{"velocity_dict":
    {
        "formula": "v=d/t",
        "variables": "v,d,t", 
        "velocity":
            {"units":"m/s", "value": 0},
        "time":
            {"units": "s", "value": 0},
        "distance":
            {"units":"m", "value": 0}
    }
}
```

Here's the Python.

```
import json


def velocity_formula():
    with open('data.json') as data_file:
        velocity = json.load(data_file)
        for value in velocity.items():
            print(value)
        print("Enter the values for each variable. (? for unknown) ")
        v=input('What is the velocity: ' )
        t=input("What is the time: ")
        d=input("What is the distance: ")
        
       
        
        if (v == "?"):
            v=float(d)/float(t)
            velocity['velocity']["value"]=v
            print("Velocity(v)=",v,velocity['velocity']["units"])
            
        elif (t == "?"):
            t=float(d)/float(v)
            velocity['time']["value"]=t
            print("Time(t)=",t, velocity['time']["units"])
        
        elif (d=="?"):
            d=float(v)*float(t)
            velocity['distance']["value"]=d
            print("Distance(d)=",d, velocity['distance']["units"])
    
        
        
        else:
            print("Try again")
```

Comment: hint: you are trying to access a key without specifying that it's a string. See correction: `velocity['velocity']["value"]`

Comment: The data file as shown is invalid. Your code is indented inproperly. Show the actual code and the actual error you get if any. Make a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show us the error log?

Answer (score 0):

You import `JSON` namely `velocity` and asked to dictionary `velocity['velocity']["value"]` to replace value. Now, the problem is `velocity_dict` which is also a key but you didn't mention anywhere to get the value. Look the following code hope you will get the point.

```
dict_vel={"velocity_dict":
    {
        "formula": "v=d/t",
        "variables": "v,d,t", 
        "velocity":
            {"units":"m/s", "value": 0},
        "time":
            {"units": "s", "value": 0},
        "distance":
            {"units":"m", "value": 0}
    }
}

print("Enter the values for each variable. (? for unknown) ")
v=input('What is the velocity: ' )
t=input("What is the time: ")
d=input("What is the distance: ")



if (v == "?"):
    v=float(d)/float(t)
    dict_vel['velocity_dict']['velocity']["value"]=v
    print("Velocity(v)=",v,dict_vel['velocity_dict']['velocity']["units"])
    
elif (t == "?"):
    t=float(d)/float(v)
    dict_vel['velocity_dict']['time']["value"]=t
    print("Time(t)=",t, dict_vel['velocity_dict']['time']["units"])

elif (d=="?"):
    d=float(v)*float(t)
    dict_vel['velocity_dict']['distance']["value"]=d
    print("Distance(d)=",d, dict_vel['velocity_dict']['distance']["units"])

else:
    print("Try again")
```

Output

```
Enter the values for each variable. (? for unknown) 
What is the velocity: ?
What is the time: 10
What is the distance: 400
Velocity(v)= 40.0 m/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add '' to call the objects because the keys in the dictionary is a string type key.
As below:

```
velocity['velocity']["value"]=v
print("Velocity(v)=",v,velocity['velocity']["units"])
```